# getting empty value in spring web service

Tags: spring, angularjs, restangular

I've created an application in Spring Rest service for receiving name from Restangular, the application is working fine but I'm getting empty values at the server side, can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**Script**

```
 Restangular.one('name',"Jhonny").get();
```

**Spring Rest Web Service**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "name/{studentName}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = APP_JSON)
@ResponseBody
public void getStudentName(@RequestBody final String studentName)
{
System.out.println("studentName::"+studentName);
}
```

**Output**

```
studentName::
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "name/{studentName}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = APP_JSON)
@ResponseBody
public void getStudentName(@PathVariable("studentName") final String studentName)
{
   System.out.println("studentName::"+studentName);
}
```

The change is to use `@PathVariable` to capture the value passed in the URL.
`@RequestBody` is used in cases where you want the whole body of the request to be binded to some object (usually the body will be JSON and the binding will the help of Jackson)

Comment: I'm getting like `2014-05-09 02:14:42.632:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:/tey/secure/jer/teyUserPage/getStudentName/Jhonny
java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Could you please post the entire code in the controller?

Comment: @Manu Glad to hear it!